# Iphone mapkit overlay

Tags: iphone, mapkit, overlay

I'm a bit confusing on the use of map overlay. Can anyone help out or post some sample code? I only need to overlay my map and draw some lines to connect some pins that I have placed.

Comment: Can you create a grid to hide parts of the map with those overlays?

Comment: I haven tried nothing like this, but of course its possible. I only draw cyrcles on my map, but you can draw cyrcles and fill it with color to obtain something that hides part of the map, I think you can also combine different filled shapes to do that.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good polyline example [here](http://spitzkoff.com/craig/?p=136).